# GRID CSS - How to center children when grid-column is defined?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, css-grid

I discovered Grid CSS recently. And I was wondering how to center children in the container (that has a display grid) when we got only two children for example. I show you a short preview of my issue.

Here, I defined 12 columns in my container. And we have 4 children with a `grid-column: span 4`. Everything works fine!

[image: Grid css 01]

But now, if we got only 2 children and I want to center them in the grid, how can I do this ? I tried to `justify-content: center` to my container but it does not working. Of course, I can place children with `grid-column: 4/7` (for the first child). But I'd like to do it automatically.

[image: Grid CSS 2]

The only solution I found is using Flexbox instead of Grid.

Thanks!

Comment: show your code pls